# PowerShell: Passing Unique Variables in Nested functions

Tags: powershell, nested-loops

Without giving out specifics I work for a Data Center

We have "Sensor data" in our database from various points, some of these sensors aren't physical sensors and are expressions to calculate various values, using a proprietary expression language.

essentially my code is readings strings, pulling out the relevant pieces of information via regex, and then querying the database to lookup these pieces of data, and in many cases the return is also an expression, so my goal is to read each expression recursively, I add some dimensional data to the return object and this allows me to build Hierarchical trees similar to:

```
Top ([Point1];[Point2])
    1 ([child of Point1])
        2 ([child of Point1 #1])
    1 ([child of Point2])
        2 ([child of Point1 #1])
        2 ([child of Point1 #2])
```

As is the code is kind of a mess, it's IF's nested in IF's nested in IF's
Ideally I'd like to be able to make a nested throwaway function, that allows me to set just a few parameters, something like

```
Function RecursiveFunction{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
     [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
     [String]$InputObject,

     [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
     [String]$Tree_Level,

     [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
     [String]$Next_Level
)

BEGIN {}

PROCESS {
        $inputobject+$tree_level = "REGEX expression"

        "More commands and queries"

        $InputObject+$Next_Level = "Result of Commands and Queries"

END{}

}
Export-ModuleMember RecursiveFunction
```

Then When I call the function Ideally I want to be able to reference unique variables from the previous tree level, for instance, keeping in mind my hierarchy is:

```
Top
 1
  2
   3
```

The construction would look something like this.

```
$InputData = Import-CSV data.csv

    ForEach($ThingTop in $InputData)
        {
        RecursiveFunction -InputObject $ThingTop -Tree_Level "Top"

        IF($InputObject1 -ne $Null)
            {
            ForEach($Thing1 in $InputObject1)

            RecursiveFunction -InputObject $Thing1 -Tree_Level "1"

            }
        }
```

This would recurse down 3 or 4 levels, If I could figure out how to dynamically rename the variables in the function this would allow me to , most likely just adding a number to the end this would allow me to make something more functional, and avoid some spaghetti code, because right now it's about 300 lines of IFs and it's easy to get lost.

Comment: Could the function process and return an object with 3 properties? The expression and a depth calculation and parent expression. No need to rename variables. Depth is actually assumed by parent child relationship though so you really just need the two I suppose.

Comment: Do you by chance have a small example of your data and how it would be processed.

Comment: Also I would be surprised if you couldnt get those ifs together with some switch statements.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're overcomplicating things. However, I know that recursion can get a little confusing at times.  What you need is to recursively call a function inside itself.  Essentially, you call a function with a the parent path. Then, inside the function, you have a loop that then enumerates all the child paths "underneath" that parent path. Then, in the loop, you call the function itself again.  I don't know your situation but here's an example.

You'll end up calling that function for every one of your paths. If you're not careful though sometimes it'll run indefinitely if you don't have some kind of condition in there to meet once you want it to stop.

```
Function Get-SomeMatch
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
        [Parameter()]
        [String[]]$Paths
    )

    ForEach ($i in $Paths)
    {   
        Get-SomeMatch -InputObject $i
    }
}

$InputData = Import-CSV data.csv

Get-SomeMatch -Paths $InputData
```